# Addition carry in a matrix MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, addition

I have a vector of values which i need to put together as a single number.

Problem is, some values are a two digit number. I need to keep the ones digit and carry up the tens digit to the next column.

Ie:

```
A=[14,34,49,41,24, 0]
```

I have added a zero value at the end to allow for a carry from the previous column.

I'm thinking I need to make a matrix so these values can be stored on the next line whilst making space for each successive carry. So it calculates like the below and then I can print the last row as my solution.

```
B=[14,34,49,41,24,0:4,35,49,41,24,0:4,5,52,41,24,0:4,5,2,46,24,0:4,5,2,6,28,0:4,5,2,6,8,2]
```

I REALLY hope someone can help me and also hope that this makes sense to you!
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: If it helps, this is the addition process after a hand written long multiplication.

Comment: Can you give a complete example, including the expected output? I am not sure if this should result in a vector or in a single number?

Comment: I don't see the relationship between `A` and `B`.  Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: A is the first row. I then added a matrix of zeros to make space for the carry calculations. B is a way that I think the calculations could be done in the matrix A with zeros rows. note the 14 in the first row - in the next row it has kept the the 4 and carried the 1 into the next column making the 34 become 35. the rest of the numbers in the row are moved down and the calculation starts again on the next line. 35 then is 5 and the 3 is carried over to the 49 in the next column to make 52. and so on til i have the final row of all single digit values.